# how to configure paypal ipn listener response in spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc, paypal-ipn

how do i configure Pay pal Instant Payment Notification listener response in spring controller.  Also is it  possible to configure Paypal IPN Listener in IPN Listener URL  like below in Paypal Merchant profile.
IPN Listener URL = http://localhost:8080/UNI_VAT/payPalIpnListener

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please can you review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide?
Your question is not currently in a form that will get much of a response

Specifically you should edit your question to include the steps that you have tried so far and the problems you got with them.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully done it in my project so hope this answer helps you.

Please follow below steps to implement paypal payment integration.

**Paypal side configurations**

1.Login to paypal business account.

2.Click on setting icon in navbar(If you want to go with URL then https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings is the URL.

3.You will get screen like below.
[image]

4.Click on my selling tools > Website preferences (screen attached below)

[image]

5.Enable Instant payment notifications by clicking on Instant payment notifications in above screen and you will get below screen(You will be asked to enter a URL on which you want paypal to redirect after successful or failure of payment. see below screen IPN is enabled.

[image]

Congratulations,you have made all the configurations required for the Paypal payment.

Now lets come to JAVA part to handle success/failure from paypal.

Create a method in controller to handle paypal redirection URL like below(you will get mulitple request parameters like "st","amt","cc","tx" status,amount,currency,transaction id etc.).

```
@RequestMapping(value="/paypal/success")  //this url should map which you configured in step 5
    public String success(ModelMap modelMap,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,Model uiModel) throws Exception{
        Enumeration<String> parameterNames = httpServletRequest.getParameterNames();

        while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {

            String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();
            System.out.println("paramName : "+paramName);
            String[] paramValues = httpServletRequest.getParameterValues(paramName);

            for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
                String paramValue = paramValues[i];
                System.out.println("paramName : " + paramName+ ",paramValue : " + paramValue);
                //your logic goes here

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: thank you for your kind help but facing problem in enabling Instant payment notifications in Paytab merchant account .